# LibGit2Sharp - The current branch is configured to merge with the reference '' from the remote, but this reference was not fetched

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm using LibGit2Sharp and after cloning the repository and try to call the PULL command, always gives the same error.
I've tried to use checkout, reset, merging and not changed.

```
public void RecuperarRepositorio()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(DS_CAMINHO_DESTINO + @"\.git"))
        CriarRepositorio();
    else
        AtualizarRepositorio();
}

private void CriarRepositorio()
{
    var path = Repository.Clone(DS_CAMINHO_GIT, DS_CAMINHO_DESTINO, RetornaCloneOptions());
}

private void AtualizarRepositorio()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(DS_CAMINHO_DESTINO + @"\.git\"))
    {
        foreach (Remote remote in repo.Network.Remotes)
            repo.Network.Fetch(remote, RetornaPullOptions().FetchOptions);

        repo.Network.Pull(RetornaAssinatura(), RetornaPullOptions());
    }
}

private CloneOptions RetornaCloneOptions()
{
    var co = new CloneOptions();
    co.BranchName = NM_BRANCH;
    co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => RetornaCredencial();
    co.CertificateCheck += delegate(Certificate certificate, bool valid, string host) { return true; }; 
    return co;
}

private PullOptions RetornaPullOptions()
{
    var po = new PullOptions();
    po.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
    po.FetchOptions.TagFetchMode = TagFetchMode.All;
    po.FetchOptions.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => RetornaCredencial();
    po.FetchOptions.CertificateCheck += delegate(Certificate certificate, bool valid, string host) { return true; };
    po.MergeOptions = new MergeOptions();
    po.MergeOptions.FileConflictStrategy = CheckoutFileConflictStrategy.Theirs;
    return po;
}
```

Comment: I would assume that 1) Either your current ref points to a now nonexistent remote branch, or 2) Your local branch was not set to track a remote branch. Fix what your local branch is tracking and that should fix it.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: I can only update using this command. How to do it with libgit2sharp? (git pull origin develop)

Comment: ever figure this out? we have the exact same problem.

Comment: I see this for empty repo's adding a file to it makes it go away.

Comment: Hi Dhiogo, I got same issue here. Did you managed to fix that?

Comment: 6 years. i dont remeber anymore